# How do i Tokenize a string?

Tags: nlp, tokenize

I want my program to know if the string is a Noun, verb , adjective or etc. and it needs to be tokenized but how do i do that?

Do i need a Database for the definition of words? using Free context grammar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much more complicated than that.

The answer to your immediate question is both.  You both look up words to see what part of speech they are, as well as analyze sentence structure to determine part of speech.

Check out http://wordnet.princeton.edu/ to see about looking up parts of speech.

I recommend GATE/Annie as a open source framework for NLP.  Apache has UIMA, although I haven't worked with it.  There is some compatibility between the projects, I believe.

Comment: thank you for the reply. is it possible integrate GATE/Annie in java program?